# Wordpress variable

Tags: wordpress, variables

I just think about that, easy to do in non cms site, but in wordpress site... i like to know YOUR approach to that problem

I have a BIG site (200 pages)... and at a lot of place, the info@something.com, the 000-000-0000 telephone and send your check to 123 easy street, Canada...

all that email, telephone, and address... should reside in one place (a post or a var) and when you need to insert it you should used the short code [tel] or [email].... but how...

is there a plusgin that can define var, or a tutorial to do that... do you only have to change it ONE  for the whole site..

Any idea is welcome.... now, find and remplace is my friend !...

thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try the Custom Config plugin:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-configs/
It will allow you to create custom global variables that are contained within the CMS (otherwise you'd be declaring these variables within the template config).

Usage to output a variable onto the page would be something like:

```
<?=get_config('myVariable','default')?>
```

Comment: pretty nice, but you have to dig into PHP, wich is a bit more complicated that shortcode lie [email]